# Readout State of Numpad

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

is it possible to read out if the NumPad is enalbed Numbers or not?

the following code (of tkinter) returns on Raspberry (VM) the same Keycode unless the state:

```
def callback(e):
    print("Keycoe:"+str(e.keycode))

root.bind("<Key>", callback)
```

Thanks